# Javascript OOP, a simple calculator that will not function

Tags: javascript, oop, object, methods

I'm building a simple calculator to incorporate it in a simple web based POS system. I do not have much experience with JS but i have programmed in C, C++ & Java extensively.

In the firefox debugger I get an exception TypeError: "this.getValue is not a function." when it is called in the method updateDisplay().

It this kind of structure not supported in JS? Calling object methods in a method of an object?

http://jsfiddle.net/uPaLS/33/

```
function KeyPad(divReference) {
    this.divDisplay = divReference;
    this.value = "0";
    this.comma = false;
}
KeyPad.prototype.getValue = function () {
    return parseFloat(this.value);
};
KeyPad.prototype.updateDisplay = function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(this.divDisplay).text(this.getValue());
    });
};
KeyPad.prototype.keyPressed = function (valueString) {
    if (valueString == '.' && this.comma === true) {
        return;
    }
    this.value = this.value + valueString;
    if (valueString == '.') {
        this.comma = true;
    }
    this.updateDisplay();
};
KeyPad.prototype.reset = function () {
    this.value = "0";
    this.comma = false;
    this.updateDisplay();
};


var keyPad = new KeyPad("#keypad_display");
```

Answer (score 2):

In your function updateDisplay , `this` doesn't refer to your KeyPad object: it refers to $(document), because <strike>you're not in the same scope</strike> of how the function is called.

```
KeyPad.prototype.updateDisplay = function () {
     //'this' is Keypad
     $(document).ready(function () {
         //'this' is $(document)
         $(this.divDisplay).text(this.getValue());
     });
 };
```

I don't think (maybe i'm wrong) that using $(document).ready here, inside a function, is a good practice. This should simply fixed your error:

```
KeyPad.prototype.updateDisplay = function () {
         $(this.divDisplay).text(this.getValue());
 };
```

As sroes says in the comment, you should use the $(document).ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var keyPad = new KeyPad("#keypad_display");
 });
```

Comment: Yeah, it would be better to put `var keyPad = new KeyPad("#keypad_display");` inside the document ready.

Comment: Glad it helps you! You can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the tick under the answer votes ;)